# Download multiple files from single object

Tags: symfony, download, twig

I have a template where I loop through a collection of Exercises. I display each exercise with its name, description, and a button to open it. I'm currently trying to add a download button for multiple files. Each Exercise has a collection of CorrigeFile (OneToMany) and I'm trying to send my collection of CorrigeFile to JS so that I can then loop on all of them to download them (I don't want to zip them). This is what I've tried so far.

```
{% for exo in exos %}
    {# display the exercise name, description and link to open it #}
    <p class="download-btn" data-files='{{ exo.corrigeFiles }}' onclick="downloadCorr(this.dataset.files)">
        <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
        Download all files
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

And the JS:

```
function downloadCorr(files) {
    for (let i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++) {
        //download it 
    }
}
```

But it's obviously not working because I think Twig can't handle raw collections like my `{{ exo.corrigeFiles }}` and I wouldn't have been able to loop through them in JS either anyway. Maybe I could supply additional data from my controller? Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: the only way is to zip them into one file after you can download them

Comment: @abderrahimesanadi I want to loop through all of them and download them one by one, I know it is possible, the problem is to create a valid array of files for JS.

Comment: have you tried `onclick="downloadCorr({{ exo.corrigeFiles|json_encode }})"` ? (maybe have to add `|raw` or `|e('html_attr')` or something after the json_encode. or you can cycle through the files in twig and try to extract some single property and build your array that way.

Comment: @Jakumi adding '| json_encode' is working but when I log the content I get an empty set. Both other options return an error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "when I log the content", also, what do you mean both other options if you add `|json_encode|raw` or `|json_encode|e('html_attr')` at least one of those should work to some extent.

Comment: @Jakumi I mean console.log()-ed it and it returned {} whereas in my controller the object wasn't empty. Anyway I got around that problem by passing additional data through my controller.